# Major opcode of failed request: 1 (X_CreateWindow) - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, opengl-es, x11

I am developing an *opengl-es* application in Linux.

My system details:

> Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
>
> 64-Bit
>
> Intel® Core™ i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4
>
> Intel® Haswell Desktop

I am initialising the egl and opengl as in 
"http://opengles-book-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/LinuxX11/Common/esUtil.c"

The code to createWindow is below

```
if(!(x11_display = XOpenDisplay(NULL)))
    {
        printf("GAL_X11WinCreate:: x11_display == NULL ==> could not open display\n");
        return EGL_FALSE;
    }
root = DefaultRootWindow(x11_display);

swa.event_mask  =  ExposureMask | PointerMotionMask | KeyPressMask;
win = XCreateWindow(
                       x11_display, root,
                       0, 0, iWidth, iHeight, 0,
                       CopyFromParent, InputOutput,
                       CopyFromParent, CWEventMask,
                       &swa
                    );

xattr.override_redirect = FALSE;
XChangeWindowAttributes ( x11_display, win, CWOverrideRedirect, &xattr );

hints.input = TRUE;
hints.flags = InputHint;
XSetWMHints(x11_display, win, &hints);

// make the window visible on the screen
XMapWindow (x11_display, win);
XStoreName (x11_display, win, "OGLES_FMWRK");

// get identifiers for the provided atom name strings
wm_state = XInternAtom (x11_display, "_NET_WM_STATE", FALSE);

memset ( &xev, 0, sizeof(xev) );
xev.type                 = ClientMessage;
xev.xclient.window       = win;
xev.xclient.message_type = wm_state;
xev.xclient.format       = 32;
xev.xclient.data.l[0]    = 1;
xev.xclient.data.l[1]    = FALSE;
XSendEvent (
            x11_display,
            DefaultRootWindow ( x11_display ),
            FALSE,
            SubstructureNotifyMask,
            &xev 
            );

*hWnd = (EGLNativeWindowType) win;
```

I am getting the below error.

```
      X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
      Major opcode of failed request:  1 (X_CreateWindow)
      Value in failed request:  0x0
      Serial number of failed request:  7
      Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: Can you compile and run HelloTriangle?

Answer (score 2):

I got similar error message before. In my case.

It's OK on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
XSetWindowAttributes    xattr;
xattr.override_redirect = 0;
```

I initial xattr to fix it.

```
XSetWindowAttributes    xattr;
memset(&xattr,0,sizeof(XSetWindowAttributes));
xattr.override_redirect = 0;
```

Maybe it can help you.